# My Dashboard isn't running from http://127.0.0.1:8050/ but code isn't showing any error

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import traceback

# Load the IPL data
ipl_matches = pd.read_csv('/IPL_Matches_2008_2022.csv')

# Define the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the app layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1("Most Match Winners in IPL"),
        dcc.Graph(id="wins-graph"),
    ]
)

# Define the callback function
@app.callback(
    Output("wins-graph", "figure"),
    Input("wins-graph", "id")
)
def update_graph(_):
    try:
        # Calculate the most wins
        most_wins = ipl_matches['WinningTeam'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
        most_wins_df = pd.DataFrame({'Wins': most_wins})
        most_wins_df.index.name = 'Team'

        # Create the plot
        fig = px.bar(
            most_wins_df,
            x=most_wins_df.index,
            y='Wins',
            color='Wins',
            title="Most Match Winners in IPL"
        )
        
        # Update the layout
        fig.update_layout(
            plot_bgcolor="#ECECEC",
            paper_bgcolor="#ECECEC",
            font=dict(
                family="sans-serif",
                color="#102111"
            )
        )

        return fig
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

# Run the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Please can somebody have a look that what the problem?

Firstly I got the error of **SystemExit: 1** but after changing the code below the code runs perfectly. But still dashboard isn't working. I removed the SystemExit error by introducing use_reloader as False. Still dashboard link isnot working. If anybody of you can have a look on my code I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Your app runs perfect on my local computer on `http://127.0.0.1:8050/`. You may have some issue with your `/etc/hosts` or a problem with the configuration of your browser; have you tried other?